# QEMU headless, GUI through VNC

Tags: android-emulator, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, android-x86

I want to create a virtual android device on my Debian server using QEMU, KVM and Android x86. The server is headless and has no GPU. I want to access the virtual android device using VNC from another workstation.

Unfortunately, I noticed 100% CPU usage when running QEMU and Android. Maybe it is because of the graphic rendering as it has no GPU. Is it possible to outsource the graphic rendering to the workstation which connects to the android device using VNC?

If not, what can I do to reduce the CPU usage?

Comment: Afaik it is not so easy. Android SDK of the google uses its own patched qemu/kvm with many android add-ons.